# `regeneratorRuntime is not defined` error in react-speech-recognition even afer running `npm i --save regenerator-runtime`

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, vite, referenceerror, uncaught-reference-error

I'm using Vite for running my react application and want to use  react-speech-recognition module but I'm getting the error `regeneratorRuntime is not defined`.

Even after running the command `npm i --save regenerator-runtime`, the error persists (BTW I'm using chrome).
It seems that the error is occurring in the `/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-speech-recognition.js` file but I don't know how to fix it, any suggestions?

BTW, yes my code is correct, but the application isn't loading due to the error

edit:
here's my code

```html
const HearingCall = () => {...

   useEffect(() => {
    const {
      transcript,
      listening,
      resetTranscript,
      browserSupportsSpeechRecognition
    } = useSpeechRecognition();  /*comment:  here is where im getting the error*/

    if (!browserSupportsSpeechRecognition) {
        console.log("browser doesnt support speech to text recognition")
    }
    else{
      SpeechRecognition.startListening
      console.log(transcript)
    }
    
  
    return () => {
    
      if (listening){
        SpeechRecognition.stopListening()
      }
    }
  },[openDialog])
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

install core-js using

```
npm install --save core-js
```

add this line at the top of the component or top of the root file

```
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
```

for me it worked in the component file and make sure that it's imported at the very top on first line... i was importing it on 4th line and it wasn't working.. wasted my whole on it. and i just put it on 1st line and it worked

Comment: i have tried that however, it gives me this error :
`Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3.`

Comment: @user22793041 can you share your code? maybe you're calling hooks at wrong palce.

Comment: @user22793041 you are calling useEffect hook inside a function that's what causing the error. move that useEffect outside the  callback function. that should resolve the issue. for more info [click here](https://legacy.reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html)